# dataframe.plot histogram change label

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a dataframe named df that looks like this

```
   success        type
1  0.197642  Technique 1
2  0.177575  Technique 2
0  0.018519  Technique 3
```

Then I plot it:
`df.success.plot(kind="bar")`

But the labels for the bars are 1,2,0. I'd like them to be the strings in the type column of my dataframe. I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to customize the histogram beyond just changing the color of the bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.plot(x='type', y='success', kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
```

[image]

I found this by looking at [the docstring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
In [11]: df.plot?
...
Parameters
----------
frame : DataFrame
x : label or position, default None
y : label or position, default None
    Allows plotting of one column versus another
```

Comment: I see. So it looks like using df.success.plot was part of the problem because when I used y=success I got an error about multiple y values.